# Is it possible to record video from popup window?

Tags: android

I have a requirement that recording video from popup window,
means I have a parent activity and at the bottom of the parent activity I have one button called record video. When I click on that button, on top of that I want show a popup screen with surfaceview for video recording.

I am able to record video with Activity, but cant do that with popup window.
Is it possible or any suggestions please...

Regards,
Pradeep_ch.

Comment: it is possible. share your some code.

Comment: you can use `AlertDialog` either..

Comment: Can you provide me any sample link or some thing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any way I am unable to get the camera preview into popup, I changed my design.
I am using View instead of Popup and adding to Activity.

Answer (score 1):

You can in fact, you'll need to use the permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```

Here is an example I wrote :

[Floating Launcher on Github](https://github.com/marshallino16/FloatingNotification)